# How do I stop duplication in <p> tag? I am trying to load data from my JSON file and display in the website with .html() function

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

[Here is a screen shot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKNcz.png)

The original file has some hard coded data and I am suppose to replace this data with the one I have in my JSON file, I tried that with this code, made some progress but every time I click on the other e mail header the same data gets placed in the

tag of my html file (index). I need to find a way to stop data from duplicating. Can somebody help me?! I am new in AJAX/JSON

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $.getJSON("email_list.js", 
            {format: "json"}).done(function(data){

            console.log(data);
            for (key in data) {
                emailID = "#" + data[key].id;

                $(".email-header")
                .eq(key).attr("id", data[key].id);

                $(emailID).find('td')
                .eq(0).attr("id", "sender" + data[key].id)
                .html(data[key].sender);

                $(emailID).find('td')
                .eq(1).attr("id", "subject" + data[key].subject)
                .html(data[key].subject);

                $(emailID).find('td')
                .eq(2).attr("id", "datetime" + data[key].datetime)
                .html(data[key].datetime);
            }
        });

    // show/hide emails when click on headers
    $("tr.email-header").click(function(){
        id = "#body " + $(this).attr("id");
        //creates the name for each file
        fileID = $(this).attr("id") + ".js";
            //console.log(id);
            $.ajax({
                url: fileID, 
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    //I need to replace the contents in the HTML file with 
                    //my JASON file contents.
                    fElement = $("tr.email-body").find("p");

                        fElement.eq(0).html(data.recipient);
                        fElement.eq(1).html(data.body);                 
                        fElement.eq(2).html(data.recipient);
                        fElement.eq(3).html(data.body);
                        fElement.eq(4).html(data.recipient);
                        fElement.eq(5).html(data.body);
                }}).fail(function() {
                        console.log(id + " - HAS AN ERROR!");               
                });
        $(this).next().eq(0).toggle();  

    });

    // hide email on click
    $("tr.email-body").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated snippet that is pulling ajax data from your github repo. Just trace through to see how we are accessing the elements in the js file.

Some additional notes:

- Try to use classes for repetitive elements like sender subject and datetime rather than ids. Then it is even easier to access them. I didn't change that.
- You have it set to reload the email every time it's header is clicked. Might want to ensure to only load once.
- You should clear out the existing html right away so the placeholder text isn't shown for a split second before the real content gets loaded.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/checonunez74/AJAX-JSONproject/master/email_list.js", {
    format: "JSON"
  }).done(function(data) {

    for (key in data) {
      emailID = "#" + data[key].id;

      $(".email-header")
        .eq(key).attr("id", data[key].id);

      f_el = $(emailID).find('td');

      f_el.eq(0).attr("id", "sender")
        .html(data[key].sender);

      f_el.eq(1).attr("id", "subject")
        .html(data[key].subject);

      f_el.eq(2).attr("id", "datetime")
        .html(data[key].datetime);
    }
  });

  // show/hide emails when click on headers
  $("tr.email-header").click(function() {
    let id = $(this).attr("id"),
      emailBody = $(this).next(".email-body"),
      emailRecipient = emailBody.find('p').first(),
      emailContent = emailBody.find('p').last();

    //make the AJAX call here
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/checonunez74/AJAX-JSONproject/master/' + id + '.js',
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(data) {
        emailRecipient.text('To: ' + data.recipient);
        emailContent.text(data.body);
      }
    }).fail(function() {
      console.log(id + " - HAS AN ERROR!");
    });

    emailBody.toggle();
  });

  // hide email on click
  $("tr.email-body").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });

});
```

```css
.email-body {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="email.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="email.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Email Inbox</h1>

  <table class="table table-hover" id="inbox">
    <thead>
      <tr class="active">
        <th>Sender</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Received</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

      <tr class="warning email-header">
        <td>Bob</td>
        <td>Re: Your brains</td>
        <td>01/03/2014 9:56pm</td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="email-body">
        <td colspan="3">
          <p>To: Tom@tom.tom</p>
          <p>Heya Tom, it's Bob, from the office down the hall...</p>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="warning email-header">
        <td>Your only friend</td>
        <td>I've been shockingly nice</td>
        <td>04/07/2011 12:34pm</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="email-body">
        <td colspan="3">
          <p>To: want@you.gone</p>
          <p>That's what I'm counting on.</p>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="warning email-header">
        <td>Mr. Fancy Pants</td>
        <td>Chances are...</td>
        <td>10/21/2005 4:16am</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="email-body">
        <td colspan="3">
          <p>To: dancing@the.parade</p>
          <p>You thought you had some fancy pants and now you know it's true.</p>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I see what you mean, I figured that was where my problem is, I am trying to come up with a different approach in order to fix that; so far my research shows that maybe appending is best, or maybe event delegation. But I still can't put together the code I need. any ideas are welcome

Comment: Can you add the JSON to your question and mock up what it should look like and act like when it works correctly?

Comment: Sure no problem, I am calling three different JSON files named by their ids, something like (100495.js) here is the contents of one of the files:
{
 "id": 100496,
 "datetime": "01/01/2018",
 "sender": "Clau J. Nunez",
 "recipient": "Sofia",
 "subject": "This is the second emil",
 "body": "This is a test for the secod e mail in the JASON file."
}

Comment: The expected outcome should be something like:
Sender                        Subject                                 Received
Clau J. Nunez             This is the second emil         This is a test for the second e mail in the JASON file

Comment: If I saw your html this would be easier, but you already know which element you clicked on using *$("tr.email-header").click(function() {*, you're already accessing it with $(this) at one point in your code. You need to use that info to replace *fElement = $("tr.email-body").find("p");* with something more precise based on $(this). I'm thinking it will be *fElement = $(this).next("tr.email-body").find("p");* and then you'll only have the two paragraphs to update eq(0) and eq(1).  -  If you add your HTML we could troubleshoot more easily. :)

Comment: Hey JasonB thanks for staying interested, here is a copy of my HTML code:

https://github.com/checonunez74/AJAX-JSONproject

Comment: There's no email_list.js in the github repo. :(

Comment: My bad! I just committed the file to the repository, that file contains the data of all the three individual .js that we have in the project.

Comment: checonunez, your ajax is wired up and working in this snippet. I mentioned some other things to change but I didn't want to make your code unrecognizable. Cheers!